# onChange method does not work

Tags: java, android, realm

I get a RealmResults in A Activity like below:

```
citySceneryBeanRealmResults = realm.where(CitySceneryBean.class).equalTo("cityid", pp.getCurrentCityId()).findAll()
```

then I get a RealmObject in another B Activity and set the realmobject a RealmChangeListener like below:

```
bean = realm.where(CitySceneryBean.class).equalTo("id", mVid).findFirst();
bean.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<CitySceneryBean>(){
        @Override
        public void onChange(CitySceneryBean element) {
            Log.i(SceneryDetailActivity.class, "onChange");
            noManagedBean = realm.copyFromRealm(element);
            refreshData();
        }
    });
```

I did confirm the ReamlObject "bean" is contained in the citySceneryBeanRealmResults, now when the citySceneryBeanRealmResults is modified, and in A Activity I confirm related bean is updated, but in B Activity the onChange method does not work , why?

Comment: "Does not work" as in "will not be called" or in "throws exception"?

Comment: Where are you closing the Realm instance for the Activity where you have .addChangeListener? if you close the Realm instance before making a modification on the data, then you might not get the callback.

Comment: Also, if `bean` (which you added the listener on) gets GCed, the listener won't be called either.

Comment: I close realm in method onDestroy, I confirm the realm is not closed before the modification.

Comment: If you can reproduce this in a sample project it would be much easier to debug. Would that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the `RealmChangeListener` is a field variable.

```
RealmChangeListener realmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener<CitySceneryBean>(){
    @Override
    public void onChange(CitySceneryBean element) {
        Log.i(SceneryDetailActivity.class, "onChange");
        noManagedBean = realm.copyFromRealm(element);
        refreshData();
    }
};

void someMethod() {
    bean = realm.where(CitySceneryBean.class).equalTo("id", mVid).findFirst();
    bean.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);  
}
```